# Lion server installation fails with "not connected to internet" error message

Tags: installation, osx-lion, osx-server

THe installation of OS X 10.7 Lion Server fails while trying to download the "server essentials". A "not connected to internet" error message appears, despite a working connection via WiFi.

What can I do to get around this problem?

An ethernet connection is not conveniently available.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. Then I unlocked my network settings and switched off the automatic proxy detection. After doing so the message did not appear anymore and I was able to download and install the server essentials.